Difference between `net.core.rmem_default` and `net.core.rmem_max`
Are net.core.rmem_default and net.core.rmem_max both per socket or is one per socket and the other is for all sockets?
This is also important since I use UDP, not TCP.

both per socket, and regardless of whether it's TCP or UDP.
As their names suggest, one is the default, the other the maximum size you can set the receive buffer to.
